# Limit download speed for files per user

Tags: webserver, download, lighttpd

How can I limit download speed for certain files like `.exe`, `.tgz` for per user downloading?

I dont have any limits set at this while and if there is about 10 users downloading a 2GB file, my bandwidth is throttled.

Comment: A possible solution might involve lighttpd's [mod_magnet](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModMagnet), identify users by lighty.env["request.remote-ip"], and some how keep track of their connections/downloads. You could look at size of file being requested and frequency of request, and if they're too frequent, start [throttling](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_trafficshaping) with connection speed. That's a bare framework, but might be able to solve your problem.

Comment: While something like `connection.kbytes-per-second = 1000` could work, the downside is that sometimes the user will not get much performance from an empty server and at other times, many users will take it down anyway. The right way is to get HTB running and then set the bucket of the connections using the `connbytes` iptables module. This will keep the website snappy and limit the downloads as needed. Don't ask for the linux commands, too long.